# holomorphic function & complex differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $z \in \mathbb{C}$. For which sign is the function f holomorphic.

$f\left(z\right) := e^x\cos \left(y\right) \pm ie^x\sin \left(y\right)$

I tried to use the definition of complex differentiation, or write f with power series. But that doesn't get me anywhere...

Can someone give me hints and some advices for this task?

Thanks to you all!

Comment: x is the real and y the imaginary part

Comment: tried $u_x = v_y$ for $f=u+v$?

Comment: aah, cauchy-riemann?? but that shows me only the differentiation, not the holomorphy, or am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints:*

- Check carefully the definitions of a function $f$ being *complex differentiable at a point $z_0$* and being *holomorphic at a point $z_0$*. The first one requires the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations. The second additionaly requires, that complex differentiability has to be given not only for $z_0$, but for each $z$ within a neighborhood of $z_0$.
- Do you know some criteria for being holomorphic? You may find helpful information at the wiki-page for *[holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function)*
- Note, the question addresses the functions 
  \begin{align*}
   z&\rightarrow e^z\\
  z&\rightarrow e^{\bar{z}}
  \end{align*}
  You might find some useful information at *[this Wolfram-page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

The function $e^z = e^{x+i y} = e^x (\cos y + i \sin y)$ is entire (holomorphic everywhere).

The function $e^\overline{z}$ is holomorphic nowhere.